# How to change Syncfunciton Hilo series' tooltip label names?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Syncfuction Hilo Series has high and low values and it automatically shows values as high and low label names. I want to change these label names to another language. Here is part of code of my work and how it looks like tooltip.

```
SfCartesianChart(
                title: ChartTitle(
                    text: 'En düşük ve en yüksek oranlar',
                    alignment: ChartAlignment.near,
                    textStyle: TextStyle(
                      color: blueLogo,
                      fontSize: 12.sp,
                    )),
                legend: Legend(
                    isVisible: true,
                    position: LegendPosition.top,
                    overflowMode: LegendItemOverflowMode.wrap),
                tooltipBehavior: TooltipBehavior(enable: true),
                primaryXAxis: CategoryAxis(
                    labelIntersectAction:
                        AxisLabelIntersectAction.multipleRows),
                primaryYAxis: NumericAxis(maximum: 150, plotBands: [
                  PlotBand(
                    start: 80,
                    end: 80,
                    borderColor: Colors.red,
                    borderWidth: 1,
                  ),
                  PlotBand(
                    start: 120,
                    end: 120,
                    borderColor: Colors.red,
                    borderWidth: 1,
                  )
                ]),
                series: <ChartSeries>[
                  HiloSeries<ChartData, String>(
                      markerSettings: const MarkerSettings(isVisible: true), 
                      name: 'Oranlar',
                      enableTooltip: true,
                      dataSource: chartData,
                      xValueMapper: (ChartData data, _) => data.unit,
                      lowValueMapper: (ChartData data, _) => data.low,
                      highValueMapper: (ChartData data, _) => data.high)
                ])
```

Output of this code sample

[image]

How can I change these high and low label names?

Comment: Please don't use anything from Syncfusion.  They are not open source, but instead require compliance with a commercial license, which might cost you significant money down the road.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `TooltipBehaviour` of the chart and construct the tooltip widget yourself. [Official syncfusion documentation is here](https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/cartesian-charts/tooltip#tooltip-template).